# Which algorithm does Python use for estimating square root value?

Tags: python, algorithm, sqrt

I wonder about which algorithm does Python use for estimating square root values ? Is it Newton or Babylonian or other ?

Answer (score 4):

In CPython, `math.sqrt` [is implemented in terms of C/POSIX `sqrt` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/168fd6453b5de15236116f9261d64601d92571ac/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1329-L1331), so the only answer to give is "whatever C/POSIX does". On systems with an assembly level square root function (e.g. x86's `fsqrt`) the C runtime may delegate to the chip, in which case you'd need to know the chip details to know how it performs the calculation.

There is [an approximate square root and a more complicated algorithm for `math.isqrt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/168fd6453b5de15236116f9261d64601d92571ac/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1578-L1720) if you care to look at it. I suspect it doesn't precisely match a textbook method, given optimizations for computers won't match the way humans optimize doing math by hand.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation; the language does not define the algorithm.  ShadowRanger already hit two common ones.  These are general, software-based methods.

However, it's quite common for the processor itself to have a machine-level SQRT function.  Intel chips have implemented basic transcendental functions in the late 1980s.  As a result, iPython simply in-lines the on-chip function; there is no software algorithm, as the on-chip code determines the value by a couple of hardware operations, deriving mantissa and characteristic in parallel.